# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence again

Tags: python, list, sorting

My code is as follows but presents me with an error message saying

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4\njohn'"
```

on the line

```
players.append(Player(elems[e], list(map(int, elems[e+1:e+4]))))
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
from operator import attrgetter


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
        self.highscore = max(scores)
        self.avgscore = sum(scores) / 3

with open('classFilea.txt') as f:
for l in f:
    l = l.strip(); # Remove the end of line char (\n)
text = f.read()
players = []
elems = text.split(',')        

for e in range(0,len(elems),4):
        players.append(Player(elems[e], list(map(int, elems[e+1:e+4]))))
    byhighscore = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('highscore'), reverse=True)
    byavg = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('avgscore'), reverse=True)

    print('')
    for p in byhighscore:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.highscore))

    print('')
    for p in byavg:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.avgscore))
```

My code is supposed to sort data sorted like :

```
Ahmed,1,6,4
John,5,3,5
Kali,5,4,7
Larry,4,7,6
```

By highest score and by average score

Edited code :

```
from __future__ import division
from operator import attrgetter


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
        self.highscore = max(scores)
        self.avgscore = sum(scores) / 3

with open('classFilea.txt') as f:
for l in f:
    l = l.strip(); # Remove the end of line char (\n)
text = f.read()
players = []
elems = text.split(',')        

for e in range(0,len(elems),4):
        players.append(Player(elems[e], list(map(int, elems[e+1:e+4]))))
    byhighscore = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('highscore'), reverse=True)
    byavg = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('avgscore'), reverse=True)

    print('')
    for p in byhighscore:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.highscore))

    print('')
    for p in byavg:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.avgscore))
```

Now the code is informing me that score is empty. 
I printed score in a separate page and it prints "[]"  I have been informed that this is due to my logic of my code. "for l in f loop. After that the current file pointer is at the end of the file, so the following f.read() won't get any data. As PM2Ring said: "You need to reorganize the logic of your code"

Comment: Is your file just one line or are the players on their own lines? You posted it as one line and your code tries to handle the player data so that they are on their own lines.

Comment: My text file is all on one line Sevanteri

Comment: Your code tries to handle the player data so that each player is on their own line.

Comment: put different players and their scores in different lines

Comment: Now i have sorted it like this                                                            Ahmed,1,6,4
john,5,3,5
Kali,5,4,7
Larry,4,7,6

Comment: However now it presents a error of TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Comment: Try `list(map(int, elems[1:]))`

Answer (score 1):

When you add a list with strings to score:

```
    players.append(Player(elems[0], map(int, elems[1:])))
```

, and than try to obtain the max:

```
    self.highscore = max(scores)
```

You obtain the error you've mentioned. At this point in your code:

```
    for line in f:
         elems = line.split(',')
         players.append(Player(elems[0], map(int, elems[1:])))
```

you need to make sure the "elems[1:]" does not carry strings. It's a parsing problem from your file. If you always have 4 elements for each person (name and 3 numbers) just give that instruction while building a line:

```
    for i in range(len(elems)//4):
         players.append(Player(elems[4*i], map(int, elems[4*i+1:4*(i+1)])))
```

Also I would advise you to remove the "map" since it does not have "len", or just replace replace:

```
    self.avgscore = sum(scores) / len(scores)
```

by:

```
    self.avgscore = sum(scores) / 3
```

If the length of the scores is always 3.

Comment: Thank you armatita, however now it states that elems is not defined and presents me with a name error

Comment: You are defining "elems" at this point "elems = line.split(',')". The recipe I gave should only happen after this. Where did you put it?

Answer (score 1):

If your text file only contains one line you need to handle it accordingly. Assuming there are three values between each name(**edited to take into account actually having multiple lines in file**):

```
with open('classFilea.txt') as f:
    players = []
    for line in f:
        elems = line.split(',')
        for e in range(0,len(elems),4):
            players.append(Player(elems[e], list(map(int, elems[e+1:e+4]))))
```

Here `e` loops over every fourth index of elems.

An alternative to this approach would be changing how you make the input file so that each line has only one `Player` data.

In addition your `Type Error` is probably due to you using Python 3, where `map` generates an iterator for performance reasons. This can be fixed by turning it back into a `list`.

Comment: M.T your code has a syntax error on the line "for e in range(0,len(elems),4)"

Comment: @JohnMasterCheifeXXX Corrected

Comment: Now it says for the line     "     elems = line.split(',') " is not defined

Comment: @JohnMasterCheifeXXX My bad again. `line` is not defined, as I instead called the file output `text`.

Comment: Yeah it works now haha thank you. But even more errors are present . Now for the line "players.append(Player(elems[e], list(map(int, elems[e+1:e+4]))))" it says there is a 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4\njohn' Whats wrong now?

Comment: your file has more than one line. `\n` is what is used to indicate newline. I'm guessing you are using windows and got the file from some Unix machine.

Comment: @JohnMasterCheifeXXX This might sound strange saying this here, but one can learn a lot from going through the code, line by line, trying to understand why the code generates a specific error or doesn't behave the way you want to, esp. if you do not understand the code completely in the first place. By googling I'm sure you could have fixed this by yourself as many people have had similar issues.